# Validation rule should not trigger red background brush on textbox

Tags: wpf, validation

I have added a validation rule to wpf text box. Whenever validation rule fails, i am showing error message in separate text block.

Additionally as default behavior, the text box border color color changes to red when validation is failed. I want to remove this behavior.

I have looked at customizing the control template, and customizing the error template. I am not able to delete the behavior.

Comment: Have a look at [Meleak's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135955/remove-red-rectangle-around-combobox) answere

Comment: answer seems helpful. Trying it out.

Comment: It has worked. Just small modification to the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small modification to [Meleaks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135955/remove-red-rectangle-around-combobox). Thanks to [Willem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/393879/willem) for providing the link.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxValidationErrorTamplate">
    <DockPanel>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder />          
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```